# Finding a spanned subspace and its basis for three given vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

For the vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ $$f_1= (-1,2,3),\quad f_2= \left(\frac16,\frac16,\frac43\right),\quad f_3= (1,-1,2)$$ find the subspace $U=\text{span} \{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and show its basis.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the vectors $(-1,2,3), (1/6,1/6,4/3)$ and $(1,-1,2)$ are linearly independent and hence form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

Showing that they are linearly independent can be done in various ways. One way that always works is to compute the row-reduced form of

$$M = \pmatrix{-1 & 1/6& 1\\2 &1/6&-1 \\ 3 &4/3 &2}.$$

In other words, show that $\text{rank}~M = 3$.

It this doesn't make any sense to you, I'd recommend you to read any standard textbook on linear algebra. But since you've already taken the exam, I assume you're familiar with all the necessary material.

Comment: @Bernard No, the rank is 3.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my row reduction :o(

Answer (score 0):

The rank is obviously the same as the rank of the system $(f_1,6f_2,f_3)$ (this is to remove denominators). Now operate row reduction on the system $(f_3,f_1, 6f_2)$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\-1&2&3\\1&1&8\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&1&5\\0&2&6\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&1&5\\0&0&-4\end{bmatrix}. $$
Hence the system has rank $3$, and $(f_1,f_2, f_3)$ is a basis.

Comment: There is an error in the third row, third column of the second matrix, I believe: $8 - 2 = 6$, not 10.

Comment: Yes that's what I've just corrected.  Thank you for pointing the error!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward.  The "span" of a set of vectors, {u, v, w}, is the set of all vectors of the form au+ bv+ cw.  A "basis" for a vector space is a set of vectors that spans the vector space **and** is linearly independent and the dimension of the vector space is the number of vectors in that basis.

Since you are asked about U, the span, it is certainly true that these three vectors span the space and it is only necessary to determine whether or not they are linearly independent.

The vectors (1, 2, 3), (1/6, 1/6, 4/3), and (1,-1,2) are linearly **de**pendent if and only if here exist numbers, a, b, c, **not all 0**, such that a(1, 2, 3)+ b(1/6, 1/6, 4/3)+ c(1, -1, 2)= (a+ b/6+ c, 2a+ b/6- c, 3a+ 4b/3+ 2c)= (0, 0, 0).  That gives the three equations a+ b/6+ c= 0, 2a+ b/6- c= 0, and 3a+ 4b/3+ 2c= 0.  If we add the first two equations, 3a+ b/3= 0.  If we subtract twice the first equation from the third, a+ b= 0.  b= -a so the 3a+ b/3= 3a- a/3= 8a/3= 0 and a= 0, b= 0 and then, from any one of the three equations c= 0.